# Trying to cut rows out of DataFrame, not working via specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to cut out some rows of my dataset if the `Area` or `Population` values are too high so that I can create a Scatter Graph based on the data. When I cut via `Population` it works fine but it doesn't with `Area`.

```
flagsCut = flags.loc[flags['Area'] < 6000]
flagsCut = flags.loc[flags['Population'] < 250]
print(flagsCut.shape)
plt.scatter(flagsCut['Area'].tolist(), flagsCut['Population'].tolist(), c='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Area')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.show()
```

results in 
[scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK7d4.png) (can't embed sorry)

As you can see, there are still 4 data points past 6000 on the x-axis but not any past 250 on the y-axis.

Any ideas on why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Check the dtype for `Areas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying your first constraint on `Area` to the `flags` dataframe, but then you apply your second constraint on `Population` again to `flags`, not the already constrained `flagsCut` dataframe.

You need to apply the second constraint to the already constrained dataframe, like so:

```
flagsCut = flags[flags['Area'] < 6000]
flagsCut = flagsCut[flagsCut['Population'] < 250]
```

Or more succintly:

```
flagsCut = flags[(flags['Area'] < 6000) | (flags['Population'] < 250)]
plt.scatter(flagsCut['Area'], flagsCut['Population'], 'b', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Area')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I originally had a line similar to `flagsCut = flags[(flags['Area'] < 6000) & (flags['Population'] < 250)]` but had `or` instead of `and` so I moved it to two lines. Forgot that I was then overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

The following should filter for both area and population in one step.

```
flagsCut = flags.loc[(flags['Area'] < 6000) | (flags['Population'] < 250)]
```

Comment: I think you are incorrect, if I used & operator, it would only filter those rows that met both conditions. My "or" operator would filter if either condition was met.